# How, in Reporting Services, can I populate a set of rows in the MIDDLE of a tablix from another dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

The setup:

The first few rows after the headers are from fixed aggregate values about the data: Total, Count, Average, that kind of thing. Then, the next ? rows are aggregates populated about individual items in the data...finally, there are more aggregates at the end.

The obvious answer is to create three tablices, but the problem with that is that it's impossible (as far as I can see) to get the tables and borders to line up perfectly so that there is no double-border, or gap, or overall strangeness in the formatting.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of columns is the same, your first instinct will do it. Use the properties window to make sure your tablix is in the same horizontal location and the column widths are the same.

Otherwise can't you just create a group (with a group header) copy your aggregate queries into the columns?

An example of the dataset and required outcome may help